# Xcopy.exe: Hide all errors (window prompt)

Tags: windows, batch, xcopy

I syncronize a folder on the hard drive with my USB device every time I insert it. For this I use a simple batch script that checks if the USB stick is inserted and if it is then do a sync by XCopy.

My problem is that if I remove the stick befor all files are synchronized I get a warning (Windows prompt) that the drive can not be found anymore.

Example XCopy command used: `xcopy Z: %CD% /E /D /C /Y`

Is there a way to stop XCopy from warning me every time?

Comment: Quick suggestion: Use Robocopy instead of XCopy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xcopy /Q Z: %CD% /E /D /C /Y
```

What the /Q does is as follows:

> /q : Suppresses the display of xcopy messages.

From http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Can you add a sentence to explain what the /Q does?  Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer.  I didn't downvote, but I suspect it was due to the original lack of explanation.  I upvoted to offset it.